# Could not create constraints and Foreign key references invalid table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create these two tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    PID INT NOT NULL,
    CID INT NOT NULL,
    FName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    LName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Person
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (PID); 
ALTER TABLE Person
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Country FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES Country(CID);
ALTER TABLE Person
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTEMPTYNAME CHECK ( Fname <> '' AND  LName <>  '' );
ALTER TABLE Person
    ADD  CONSTRAINT CHK_GENDER CHECK (Gender in ('M', 'F','O'));


CREATE TABLE Country 
(
    CID INT NOT NULL,
    CName VARCHAR(56),
);

ALTER TABLE Country
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Country PRIMARY KEY (CID); 
ALTER TABLE Country
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_NOTEMPTYCOYNTRY CHECK  (CName <> '');
```

As I implemented these two tables, I get two errors:

> Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
>   Foreign key 'FK_Country' references invalid table 'Country'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How can I deal with these errors?

Comment: Try creating "country" table first, then other table P

Comment: Just to expand on @ErayBalkanli's comment in case you didn't understand why; The foreign key cannot be created because the target table for the foreign key does not exist at the time `P` is created.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli you should expand that slightly to explain why and post it as an answer.

Comment: i am getting the error that there is an object name "C" already in the table

Comment: That makes no sense with the code you posted. You have a typo somewhere.

Comment: i have changed the table's name from "COUNTRY" TO "C" because i was getting the same error i mentioned previous. But again no progress

Comment: This new error is probably because you have a table named C already. Do yourself a favor and don't name things like that. I noticed you also created a table named P but then immediately alter a table named Person.

Comment: Ok what do you recommend to fix this problem?  Thank you for the feedback until now

Comment: Start by dropping the extraneous tables. Then create table person and country. Then add foreign key constraints.

Comment: And how i confirm that all the tables have dropped correctly?

Comment: Refresh the object explorer in SSMS and look at the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The table `Country` must be created first because it is your major table including the Primary Key that will be used as a foreign key for another tables.

First, make sure you did not create the tables yet, please drop first if you did, if there is no data the table includes. You can "refresh" the tables section and check if the tables are there. Or you can simply do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tablename', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE tablename;
```

After making sure the tables you want to create are not already existing, create the table that should include the key that will be used as a foreign key in another table later to provide a relationship FIRST. It is `COUNTRY` for your question.

```
Create table Country (...) ...
```

After you are sure that Country table is created with the primary key constraint, you can create other table `P` and make it related to your Country table by using its primary key as foreign key.